# In a UFD, why does $ab | c^n$ implies $ab | c$?

Tags: unique-factorization-domains

In a UFD, if I have two irreducible elemnts, $a$ and $b$ such that $ab | c^n$, why does this imply that $ab | c$?

**edit**

Here $a$ and $b$ are different and coprime.

Comment: It suffices to show that every irreducible element is prime in a UFD

Comment: you should probably add 'distinct' irreducible elements ($a\neq b$)

Comment: So if I show that every irreducible is prime in a UFD, then since $ab | c^n$ then $a | c^n$ and $b|c^n$ so by induction (and the fact that $a$ and $c$ are prime) $a|c$ and $b|c$ but then...

Answer (score 1):

The above is not true unless $a,b$ are coprime, else we may take the example $a=-b=c=2$ in the UFD $\mathbb Z$, where $ab =- 4 | 2^2 = 4$ but $ab =-4\nmid 2$.

HINTS :

- Every element in a UFD can be written as a product of irreducible elements. Use this to conclude that an element in a UFD is irreducible if and only if it is prime.
- By unique factorization, the factorization of $c^n$ can be determined from the factorization of $c$.
- If one of $a$ or $b$ don't appear in the factorization of $c$, then ...

Comment: $\,a\neq b$ is not sufficient since it can still fail if they are associate (differ by a unit factor) - see my answer

Comment: Correct, should have realized that.  I will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

In a UFD irred's are prime so $\,a,b\mid c^n\,\Rightarrow\, a,b\mid c,\,$ which implies $\,ab\mid c\,$  **if** $\,a,b\,$ are coprime $(\!\!\iff\! a\nmid b,\,$ by $\,a\,$ prime). Else it may fail, e.g. for any unit $u\!:\, $ $\, a(au)\mid a^2\,$ but not $\, a(au)\mid a.\,$

To prove it you can either directly use existence and uniqueness of irreducible factorizations, or else employ well-known consequences such as Euclids Lemma $\,(a,c)=1,\, a\mid cd\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid d$

Comment: How to show  ab | c using existence and uniqueness of irreducible factorization? Do you decompose $a$ , $b$ and $c$ into irreducible factors? $a=u_a a_1...a_m, b=u_b b_1...b_n, c=u_c c_1...c_l$?

Comment: @roi_saumon $\,a,b\,$ are already prime, being irred's in a UFD. Consider the complete (unique) prime factorizations of both sides of $\,c^n = abd\,$  The primes $a$,$b$ occur in the RHS factorization, so they mist also occur on the RHS (up to unit factors),. But the primes on the RHS are the same as those in $c$, again using uniqueness, since a prime factorization of $c^n$ arises from that of $c$ by duplicating each prime $n$ times. Uniqueness (and existence) is used many times in the proof so be sure to *explicitly* mention each use to be completely rigorous.